# Proof that a set is open/closed

Tags: general-topology

$M = \{(x,y) \in\mathbb R^2: x>0, y \geq(1/x)\}$.

My first idea was to draw M in the first quadrant just to see if I can easily determine wheater it is open or closed. Doing this I see that I can choose x as small as I want provided that is greater than 0. Therefore also y will never be 0. Thus i followed that there will be also a very very small ball centered at some point in $M$ and so it is open.
To show more mathematically that it is  open I should find for all $\epsilon > 0$ $B_\epsilon(x_0,y_0)$ s.t. $||(x,y) - (x_0,y_0)||<\epsilon$. But I really struggle with choosing an appropriate $\epsilon$ as this is really new for me. Maybe you could give me some hint/help?

If i wanted to proof that $M$ it is closed I should proof that $M^{c}$ is  open. But I would then face the problem that x could be 0 and 1/0 is not defined so I don't know how I should think about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### $M$ is not open

Because of the "$\geq$" condition for $y$, one should be able to centre a ball in $(x,y)=(x,\frac{1}{x})$, but this ball always goes out of $M$ by the left and by below (I suggest to draw it).

Replacing "$\geq$" by ">" would make $M$ open because $(x,\frac{1}{x})$ would no longer be in $M$

### $M$ is closed

Indeed, one must prove that $M^c$ is open. When $x=0$, the fact that $\frac{1}{x}$ is not defined implies that no point on the axis $(0,y)$ will be in $M$. This is equivalent to say that the entire $(0,y)$ axis is in $M^c$. Moreover, around each point $(0,y)$ one *can* construct a ball completely contained in $M^c$ (again I suggest to draw it)

Comment: The latter does not suffice to prove that $M$ is closed. Consider $(1 - \delta, 1 - \delta) \in M^C$. What is your ball there?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't chose an $\epsilon$ because the set isn't open. Consider $(1,1)\in M$ for example. Now note that
$$M^C = \{(x,y) \in\mathbb R^2 | x\le 0 \text{ or } y < \frac1x\}$$
So $x$ can be $0$ but then $y$ is arbitrary because no point $(0, y)$ is in $M$ for any $y$.
*Can you show that $M^C$ is open yourself?*

Comment: Ok i know get where my mistake was to think that M is open and I know where my mistake was. But i still struggle with shwoing that $M^C$ is open. I know that i have to construct e ball with radius $\epsilon$ s.t. $||(x,y)-(x_0,y_0)|| < \epsilon$. If i choose $\epsilon=min{x_0}$, then $\epsilon > ||(x,y)-(x_0,y_0)|| > ||(x-x_0||= |x-x_0|.$ Then $\epsilon > |x-x_0|$ . But then I am stuck again.

Comment: @Methamortix It should be easier to show that any convergent sequence in $M$ converges to a point in $M$ if you are allowed to do that. Else take a look at the distance of $(x_0,y_0)$ to the graph of $x\mapsto \frac1x$. It will only be interesting if $x_0, y_0 > 0$.